# Problem open documents in Office 2016 from SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, office, office-2016

I encountered problems using `SharePoint 2013` and `Office 2016`. Open a document stored in a SP2013 DocumentLibrary, using a Office 2016 client, results in a blanc document.
The clients are behind a proxy. By disabling it it works great...
I tried to add "http://mysharepoint" to the trusted sites, did not help.

Did somebody have the same issue?

Comment: Hi - I noticed that your question title seem to be wrong? In the title you have Office 2013 and SP 2016, but the question is about the opposite - SharePoint 2013 and Office 2016.

Comment: Oh sorry, little mistake. It is Office2016 and SP2013

Comment: What kind of proxy is that? Does it have a log? Maybe there are any records like "attack detected" in it?